# Concatenate an input argument into a splice call

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to reproduce the code lines:

```
purchase = () => {
    const eventDetails = {...this.state.events.event0002};
}
```

With the following, that takes "eventID" as an input (which at some point could have a value of "event0002") and adds it to "....state.events." to create "...state.events.eventID".

```
purchase = (eventID) => {
    const eventDetails = {`...this.state.events. $(eventID)`};
}
```

Within an Event Handler, I am attempting to incorporate an input argument into a code line that performs the splice function.

More specifically, I am attempting to replace "purchaseHandler1" and "purchaseHandler2" with a single Event Handler called "purchaseHandlerAll" which receives the "eventID" argument.

In all the Event Handlers I want "eventDetails" to be eventually assigned to the "events.activeEvent" state variable.

The code below successfully performs this assignement in the "purchseHandler1" and "purchseHandler2 Event Handlers, but does not in "purchaseHandlerAll".

```
    state = {
        events: {
            event0001: {
                eventID: "0001",
                eventName: "Rock Concert",
            },
            event0002: {
                eventID: "0002",
                eventName: "Dinner",
            },
            activeEvent: {
                eventID: "",
                eventName: ""
            }
        }
    };

    showPurchaseWindowHandler1 = () => {
        const allEvents = {...this.state.events};
        const eventDetails = {...this.state.events.event0001};
        allEvents.activeEvent = eventDetails;
        this.setState({events: allEvents})
    }

    showPurchaseWindowHandler2 = () => {
        const allEvents = {...this.state.events};
        const eventDetails = {...this.state.events.event0002};
        allEvents.activeEvent = eventDetails;
        this.setState({events: allEvents})
    }

    showPurchaseWindowHandlerAll = (eventID) => {
        const allEvents = {...this.state.events};
        const eventDetails = {`...this.state.events. $(eventID)`};
        allEvents.activeEvent = eventDetails;
        this.setState({events: allEvents})
    }
render () {
    return (
        <div>   
            <h3 close={this.purchaseHandler1}></h3>

            <h3 close={this.purchaseHandler2}></h3>

            <h3
                eventID={this.state.events.event0001.eventID}
                close={(eventID) => purchaseHandlerAll(eventID)}>
            </h3>
            <h3
                eventID={this.state.events.event0002.eventID}
                close={(eventID) => purchaseHandlerAll(eventID)}>
            </h3>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the `$` in your code?

Comment: What error? What is the expected income? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I thought that the "$" was a way to concate values together.

Comment: @RafaelC, and what are you trying to concatenate?

Comment: Hey mgarcia, thank you for the follow up message, I just added a few sentences at the beginning of my post to address your question.